# Mapping an array of rows to Hibernate and fetch result set

Tags: arrays, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, row

Given this basic SQL query

```
val sqlQuery = """
    SELECT
    ARRAY[
        ROW(1, 'Row 1'),
        ROW(2, 'Row 2'),
        ROW(3, 'Row 3')
    ] AS array_of_rows;
""".trimIndent()
val result = em.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery).singleResult
```

When I run it, Hibernate fails to execute the query with this error message

***Could not convert 'org.postgresql.util.PGobject' to 'java.lang.Class' using 'org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.ClassJavaType' to wrap***

Is there any way to tell JPA/Hibernate to just map it into e.g. an Array of ***class Entry(val a: Int, val b: String)*** or into a Map<Int, String>?